# How to decompose the java file into methods, class declaration, variable declaration, package declaration etc

Tags: java, decompiler

Sample program for the above scenario.

```
package x.y;

class myClass {
    void sun() {
    // somestatement
    }

    @someannotation
    void add() {
    // somestatement
    }

}
```

I would expect the above class should be decomposed  in below format.

```
package x.y;

class myClass {
}
void sun() {
    // somestatement
}
@someannotation
void add() {
    // somestatement
}
```

Is there any utility available?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all...

Comment: Currently you define your methods outside of `myClass`, so this won't compile.

Comment: @yogarajkv Please explain what you mean with "decompose". Your examples look like you are asking "I have something that is supposed to be Java source code, but syntax is partially messed up - how do I turn that into valid java source code". Is that really your question?

Comment: i need to split my java code to methods, variable declaration, package declaration etc.I am not going to compile the decomposed java code.